How to get max date value across multiple tables and different columns names into bigquery?
I need a SQL query or a procedure to get the max data value across multiple tables. I found the information into big query schema.
Now I need the max value of all date columns across all tables.
With this query I obtained all tables and columns.
select table_name, column_name
from db.Information_Schema.Columns
where data_type in (Timestamp, Date)
and column_name not in (ingestion_date)


Hi @Ilario, Does these link1 and link2 help you?
